# How to merge two rethinkdb documents using some function

Tags: rethinkdb

I want to translate a merge function from the following JS code to us in RQL:

```js
var d1 = {
  del: {
    1: {n: 1, v: 100, vFx:[100, 110]},
    2: {n: 1, v: 100, vFx:[100, 110]}
}};
var d2 = {
  del: {
    2: {n: 1, v: 100, vFx:[100, 110]},
    3: {n: 1, v: 100, vFx:[100, 110]}
}};

function merge(d1, d2) {
    for(k in d2.del){
        v = d2.del[k];
        d1v = d1.del[k];
        if(!d1v){
            d1.del[k] = v;
        } else{
        d1v.n += v.n;
        d1v.v += v.v;
        for(var i = 0,  _len = v.vFx.length; i < _len; i++)
            d1v.vFx[i] += v.vFx[i];
        }
    }
};

// test
merge(d1, d2);
console.log(d1);

// GOAL
r.do(d1, d2, merge)  // this of course doesn't work
```

My main problem is how to iterate through keys of a document? `r.forEach` requires me to make a save inside. My use case is that I want to use this `merge` function in update:

```js
rqlexpr.update(merge(d1, r.row))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map over the keys of a document with `keys`, and construct an object with `object`.  For example:

```
d1.merge(
  r.object(
    d2('del').keys().concatMap(function(key) {
      return r.branch(
        d1('del').hasField(key).not(),
        [key, d2('del').getField(key)],
        [key, d1('del').getField(key) + d2('del').getField(key)]
      )
    })
  )
)
```

Comment: and to loop over keys in both objects one can use `d1('del').keys().setUnion(d2('del').keys()).map(function ... )`